# Работа с сокетами в Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, сокет

Всем доброго времени суток! В Objective-C можно отправить пакет на устройство с помощью такой строки кода

> [udpSocket sendData:data toHost:host port:port withTimeout:-1 tag:tag];

Как можно принять пакет-ответ от устройства?
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Смотря, что Вы скрываете под udpSocket.

Comment: udpSocket = [[GCDAsyncUdpSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

из проекта https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket

Comment: Так я ж уж ответил про это самое ))

Comment: Ой, Стас,  это я корявый не заметил :)

Answer (score 2):

Доводилось использовать данную библиотеку для синхронизации двух iOS-устройств в пределах одной Wi-Fi сети. Нужно заметить что Вы пожалуй изначально не понимаете смысл и условия использования  протокола UDP. UDP сам по себе (как антагонист TCP) служит для быстрой передачи мелких пакетов данных где не предполагается высокоточность и надежность передачи данных. В связи с этим в UDP изначально не предполагаются никакие проверки на принимающей стороне точности прихода пакетов, их количество и прочее. Этот протокол подходит для управления например midi или скажем спуском затвора фотоаппарата, где вам нужно послать короткую команду -  символ или булево значение (хотя небольшие текстовые значения тоже поддерживаются этой библиотекой). Если Вам необходимо в ответ принимать какие-то данные (даже такие как проверка того что Ваш сигнал дошел до приемника) то UDP это не то что Вам нужно. Хотя чисто программно можно обрабатывать получение данных и слать на них ответ, это не имеет смысла так как и в первой и во второй стадии (прием-ответ) Вы можете недополучить данные что естественно для этого стандарта

Comment: Да! Мы еще видео по нему передаем, так как не страшны потери, а важна скорость доставки, без буферизации TCP.

Answer (score 1):

Я не использовал библиотеку, просто смотрю [документацию](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket/wiki/Intro_GCDAsyncSocket) и пытаюсь догадаться, как это делается:

Вы создаёте экземляр класса GCDAsyncUdpSocket:

```
[[GCDAsyncUdpSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
```

Затем внутри вашего self (ведь вы назначили его делегатом) вам нужно объявить метод `socket:didReadData:withTag:`

```
- (void)udpSocket:(GCDAsyncUdpSocket *)sock didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
                                               fromAddress:(NSData *)address
                                         withFilterContext:(id)filterContext {
    NSLog(@"Did read data: %@", data);
}
```

Comment: Я так полагаю, вы недавно на территории Objective-C. Задавайте вопросы, если неясно, что я написал.

Comment: Только что заметил, что вы используете GCDAsyncUdpSocket, а я написал просто для GCDAsyncSocket, - сейчас подправлю. Хотя суть всё равно та же.